# Comparing two strings with different orders

Tags: c#, string

I have a dictionary with a list of strings that each look something like:

```
"beginning|middle|middle2|end"
```

Now what I wanted was to do this:

```
List<string> stringsWithPipes = new List<string>();
stringWithPipes.Add("beginning|middle|middle2|end");
...

if(stringWithPipes.Contains("beginning|middle|middle2|end")
{
 return true;
}
```

problem is, the string i'm comparing it against is built slightly different so it ends up being more like:

```
if(stringWithPipes.Contains(beginning|middle2|middle||end)
{
 return true;
}
```

and obviously this ends up being false. However, I want to consider it true, since its only the order that is different.
What can I do?

Comment: Why are you storing it as a list of `string`? Why isn't it a list of list of string for example? If pipes in different order mean different things, `string` is not the correct way to store a combination.

Comment: split on '|', remove empties, and validate that both arrays contain the same items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split on a delimeter:

```
 var searchString = "beginning|middle|middle2|end";
 var searchList = searchString.Split('|');

 var stringsWithPipes = new List<string>();
 stringsWithPipes.Add("beginning|middle|middle2|end");
 ...

 return stringsWithPipes.Select(x => x.Split('|')).Any(x => Match(searchList,x));
```

Then you can implement match in multiple ways

First up must contain all the search phrases but could include others.

```
 bool Match(string[] search, string[] match) {
    return search.All(x => match.Contains(x));
 }
```

Or must be all the search phrases cannot include others.

```
 bool Match(string[] search, string[] match) {
    return search.All(x => match.Contains(x)) && search.Length == match.Length;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split your string on `|` and then split the string to be compared, and then use `Enumerable.Except` along with `Enumerable.Any` like

```
List<string> stringsWithPipes = new List<string>();
stringsWithPipes.Add("beginning|middle|middle2|end");
stringsWithPipes.Add("beginning|middle|middle3|end");
stringsWithPipes.Add("beginning|middle2|middle|end");

var array = stringsWithPipes.Select(r => r.Split('|')).ToArray();

string str = "beginning|middle2|middle|end";
var compareArray = str.Split('|');

foreach (var subArray in array)
{
    if (!subArray.Except(compareArray).Any())
    {
        //Exists
        Console.WriteLine("Item exists");
        break;
    }
}
```

This can surely be optimized, but the above is one way to do it.

Comment: I think you want to negate that `Except`. That is `if (!subArray.Except(compareArray).Any())`. The `Except` list should be empty if the two collections contain the same elements. Or am I confused?

Comment: @JimMischel, no you are not confused, you are absolutely right. placed `!` before `Any`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead::

```
if(stringWithPipes.Any(P => P.split('|')
                             .All(K => "beginning|middle2|middle|end".split('|')
                             .contains(K)))
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: This looks great but it never finds the value in the List<string>. It's so clean though, would love for this to work.

Comment: There's multiple errors so this won't even compile, and it will never find the result either your LINQ is wrong.

Comment: That's not going to work. If `Intersect.Count()` returns 0, it means that there were no matching items. You'd want to check if the count was equal to the count of items in the string you're comparing against. On a secondary note, if you ever find yourself writing `if (foo.Count() == 0)`, you should replace that with `if (!foo.Any())`. `Count()` could require enumerating the entire list. `Any()` would only have to check, at most, one.

Answer (score 0):

That should work.

```
List<string> stringsWithPipes = new List<string>();
stringsWithPipes.Add("beginning|middle|middle2|end");

string[] stringToVerifyWith = "beginning|middle2|middle||end".Split(new[] { '|' }, 
                                                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (stringsWithPipes.Any(s => !s.Split('|').Except(stringToVerifyWith).Any()))
{
    return true;
}
```

The Split will remove any empty entries created by the doubles `|`. You then check what's left if you remove every common element with the `Except` method. If there's nothing left (the `! [...] .Any()`, `.Count() == 0` would be valid too), they both contain the same elements.